# Google Mobile Vision commercial use

Tags: android, android-vision, google-vision

I could not able to find an actual answer after researching a lot on the Internet.

I want to use Google Mobile Vision library in the enterprise (commercial) application.

There are some alternatives libraries which is free for commercial use, but I want to work on google libraries which provides a lot of nice features ( face detection, barcode reader, ocr, etc..) however I could not able to find any commercial pricing information for [Google Mobile Vision Libary](https://developers.google.com/vision/)

Has anyone have any knowledge on it?

Comment: there is no clear answer. All I need to know it is free or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202190/google-mobile-vision-api-license-for-comercial-app                                                                                               
This link is broken